# WPF binding issues with resource dictionaries

Tags: wpf, resources

I have developed a custom data grid control.  This control has two parts, one is the custom template used by the data grid itself and the other is my custom control which adds a title area to the data grid.

I have a class called CustomDataGrid, here is the XAML.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MDT_Designer.Presentation.ScreenControls.CustomDataGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="CDataGrid" >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dictionary" Source="CustomizedControls.xaml"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=CDataGrid, Path=TitleAreaHeight}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=CDataGrid, Path=GridAreaHeight}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="TitleArea" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="{Binding ElementName=CDataGrid, Path=TitleBackColor}" >
        <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=CDataGrid, Path=TitleAlignment}">
            <TextBlock Name="TitleText" Text="{Binding ElementName=CDataGrid, Path=Title}" Margin="2,0,0,0" FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=CDataGrid, Path=TitleFontFamily}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=CDataGrid, Path=TitleTextColor}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="DataGridArea" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray" VerticalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Background="AliceBlue" >
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In my CustomDataGrid.xaml.cs file I have defined properties as such.

```
    public static DependencyProperty TitleAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TitleAlignment", typeof(HorizontalAlignment), typeof(CustomDataGrid));
    public HorizontalAlignment TitleAlignment
    {
        get { return (HorizontalAlignment)base.GetValue(TitleAlignmentProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(TitleAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }
```

I am just showing one as a sample, and this works.  I do wish that I could change the binding in the XAML to get rid of ElementName=CDataGrid, but any way I have as an alternative doesn't work.

Now to my problem.  My custom template for the data grid control itself is stored in the dictionary CustomizedControls.xaml.

Here is one example of binding issues.  I had to create this resource.

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HeaderBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" >
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkColorKey}}" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Then I use it in Border definition for the column header.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="columnHeaderBorder" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3,0,3,0" 
            Background="{DynamicResource HeaderBackgroundBrush}"> 
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="columnHeaderPresenter"  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Style="{DynamicResource HeaderContentStyle}" />
                    </Border>

                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripperStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then to change it in my code behind I have to do this.

```
        LinearGradientBrush headerBrush = (LinearGradientBrush)TryFindResource("HeaderBackgroundBrush");
        headerBrush.GradientStops[0] = new GradientStop(brush.Color, 0.0);
```

I cannot change the brush itself, I can just change a property of the brush.  I have tried every binding technique I can think of, but nothing seems to work when the style is in a dictionary.

What I would like to be able to do is somehow bind something like BorderLightColor, which is BorderBrush setting, so that in my code behind I can change it's value.

Any help would make my day, it would make my whole weekend in fact.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you change the brush?  You should be able to just assign the brush reference to the control.  Does this not work?  FindResource should search the Parent Element of the FrameworkElement you are calling it on and up the tree, the application resources, then Themes ending in System Resources.  Forgive my VB...

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim MyBrush2 as Brush = Me.FindResource("Brush2")   
    Me.MyRect.Background = MyBrush2
End Sub
```

And the window contents:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brush1" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Brush2" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF0800FF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="MyRect" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63,66,0,174" Width="242" Background="{DynamicResource Brush1}" />
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="60" Margin="0,117,95,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am a little confused on your response.  What I want to do is change the brush that is bound to the control through the style.  Perhapss I just need to always create and assign the brush programatically and not bother using the binding.  I will give this a try.

Comment: My other big issue is the binding from a dictionary.  I cannot bind to any properties that are defined in dictionary.  If I define a style in the UserControl.Resources section I can bind it to a DepandancyProperty exposed in code and manipulate it in the code behind.  However, I move this same style to a dictionary and I cannot appear to make it bind to the depandancy property defined in my code.  I'm tempted to just move everything out of the dictionary, so it will work, but I'd really rather know what I am doing wrong, or have missed doing.

Comment: If it is styles you are having problems with, you could always create an otherwise empty style in UserControl.Resources and have it based on a resouce elsewhere.  Then it would reflect that other style, but be defined in the UserControl.  Changes to the ResourceDictionary version would carry over.